# How to pass a java class as a reference at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to pass a class as an argument to a function. But I have the string variable which contains name of that class.

Comment: search online for "Reflection Java"

Comment: Can you show us some code, an example of how you would like it to work? I suspect that you may be using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static method of `Class` class

```
 yourMethod(other arguments,..., Class.forName("name of your class in string Formate.."));
```

this method return a `Class class object for your class...`

Answer (score 4):

This is the general method, you'll need to use a fully qualified class name.

```
myInstance.myMethod (Class.forName("fully.qualified.ClassName"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 Class.forName("Foo")
```

but the corresponding class must be in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection:

```
String className = "goo";
Class c = Class.forName(className);
foo(c);
```